# How can I run mocha tests by using a regex for matching on file names?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I am trying to run multiple `js` tests using `mocha`.  I want to match on filenames using a `regex`, but according to the [documentation](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/) you can only use a `regex` to match on `describe` blocks.  All of my `spec` files are named `*.spec.js`, so I would assume I would be able to run just those files easily.  Is there a way/plugin that I can match on the filenames that end in `.spec.js`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can pass a glob expression to mocha like this:

`mocha *.spec.js`

If you do not specify a glob it defaults to `mocha test/*.js`.

The regexp you are refering to is the "grep" option which works on test names.